# OnTouchListener for LongClick

Tags: android, camera, ontouchlistener, mediarecorder

Simple question. I have a button in which I set both an OnClick and an OnLongClick listener. The onclick is for taking photos, and the longclick is for taking videos. On longclick, I start recording for as long as the button is pressed, at which point I stop recording. However, that does not work with my code:

```
photoButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Miles", "onlong");
            invisiblizeAllButtons();
            cameraPreview.startVideo();
            v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Log.v("Miles", "ACTION UP");
                            cameraPreview.stopVideo();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            });
            return true;
        }

    });
```

The logs that are printed come in this order: ONLONG, ACTIONUP, and in stopVideo(), "STOPVIDEO". So the syntax seems to be working; however, my recorder does not stop recording:

```
public void stopVideo() {
        Log.v("Miles", "STOP VIDEO");
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.release();
    }
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as soon as I posted this. I had to call stopPreview() on the Camera object I was using to stop the video. The recording itself had stopped, but not visually.